# Turn flutter widgets to grayscale

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to turn an arbitrary widget to grayscale? I used

```dart
ColorFiltered(
   colorFilter : ColorFilter.mode(
     Colors.grey,
     BlendMode.saturation,
   ),
   child : child,
);
```

But the transparent part of the widget become opaque grey color

Comment: you need `ColorFilter.matrix`

Comment: @pskink how can I use `ColorFilter.matrix`, consider that I asked about arbitrary widget, is there anyway to generate `ColorFilter.matrix` dynamically?

Comment: i mean you need `colorFilter : ColorFilter.matrix(...)` instead of `colorFilter : ColorFilter.mode(...)`

Comment: @pskink Can you please show me how?

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/ColorFilter/ColorFilter.matrix.html - you have 3 examples in the docs

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As said by [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) you can simply use the `ColorFilter.matrix` as explained in the [Flutter documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/ColorFilter/ColorFilter.matrix.html):

> A greyscale color filter (values based on the Filter Effects Spec):
>
> ```dart
> const ColorFilter greyscale = ColorFilter.matrix(<double>[
>   0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722, 0, 0,
>   0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722, 0, 0,
>   0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722, 0, 0,   0,      0,      0,      1, 0, ]);
> ```

### Code

Which can be used like this:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const ColorFiltered(
      colorFilter: ColorFilter.matrix(<double>[
        0.2126,
        0.7152,
        0.0722,
        0,
        0,
        0.2126,
        0.7152,
        0.0722,
        0,
        0,
        0.2126,
        0.7152,
        0.0722,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
      ]),
      child: FlutterLogo(size: 48),
    );
  }
}
```

### Screenshot

I've also put the base color version for comparison:

[image]

[You can test the full code on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=b7730596e3d7facde8bf465391318b10&null_safety=true)